# why material-ui takes too much space?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, material-ui

I am using webpack to bundle my react project. My project depends on material-ui for below component:

```
material-ui/Dialog
material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme
material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider
material-ui/FlatButton
material-ui/TextField
```

webpack-bundle-size-analyzer reports material-ui takes 1.07MB size. Below is my webpack config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
var CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

const PATHS = {
  react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react', 'dist', 'react.min.js'),
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, './dist')
};

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './app/index.jsx',
    android: './app/utils/platform_android.js',
    ios: './app/utils/platform_ios.js',
    web: './app/utils/platform_web.js',
    vendor: [
      'axios',
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-redux',
      'react-router',
      'react-router-redux',
      'redux',
      'redux-thunk',
      'react-alert',
      'sha1',
      'moment',
      'nuka-carousel',
      'react-cookie',
      'material-ui',
      'react-spinkit',
      'react-tap-event-plugin',
      'react-tappable',
      'history',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  watch: false,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  relativeUrls: true,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.less'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    alias: {
      normalize_css: __dirname + '/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css',
    }
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.js$/,
      //   exclude: /node_modules/,
      //   loader: 'jshint-loader'

      // }
    ],
    loaders: [

      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets=es2015',
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!less",
      },
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
      {test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"},
      // {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader?name=/public/icons/[path]/[name].[ext]"},
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader?presets=es2015']
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-sprite',
        include: /public\/icons/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
      minimize: true
    }),
    new NpmInstallPlugin({
      save: true // --save
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
      }
    }),
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildStart: ['echo "Webpack Start"'],
      onBuildEnd: [
        'cp ./dist/*.js ../assets/dist/;rm -fr dist/web;' +
        'mkdir -p dist/web/dist;cp ./dist/*.js ./dist/web/dist/;cp ./index.html ./dist/web/;cp -r public dist/web/',
      ]
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */["vendor"], /* filename= */"[name].bundle.js", Infinity),
  ],
  devServer: {
    colors: true,
    contentBase: __dirname,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    port: 9093,
    progress: true,
    stats: {
      cached: false
    }
  }
}
```

I already tried to use CompressionPlugin, UglifyJsPlugin to optimize my bundle files but it still takes more than 1MB. How can I reduce its size? I don't want to use gzip since my app is running on webview on mobile device and some of them doesn't support gzip encoding.

Comment: How did you solve it? I'm working on an app that uses most of the material-ui components and after pacaking material-ui in a separate bundle, using minification (webpack with UglifyJSPlugin) the size is about 700kb. Did you reduce that number?

Comment: import only the component you need from material-ui instead of importing everything. This will save a lot spaces. But 700KB is more like a reasonable size.

Comment: we use almost all components. Size of 700kb is too much for mobile.

Comment: It makes sense for 700kb if you are using most of the components. You can use gzip to reduce the size which is supported by most of http servers.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I figured out what the problem. In my webpack config file, I separate all vendor js into a different js bundle file. And I listed 'material-ui' there. When package my app, the whole 'material-ui' library will be packaged into vendor.js. I have to remove the material-ui from vendor list, in this way only the components required by my source code will be packaged.

Comment: May I ask what size your app ended up being? I am using material-ui for a simple test and can't get the app below 488 Kb.

Comment: It is more than 600KB now.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you could do to reduce the size:

1. Make sure you are only requiring in the components you need from `material-ui` and not the whole library
2. Try using [Minifyify](https://github.com/ben-ng/minifyify)
3. See more suggestions in [this](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1421) GitHub Issue.

Comment: I have avoid using require 'material-ui' whole library. I import only the component I use as listed in my post. And I am using webpack and not want to change to browserify.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for Option 2 listed in their documentation here: [Minimizing Bundle Size](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/). They suggest this provides a much better experience for both developers and users, I think with much faster loading times for both.

1. Setup your Babel configuration with `babel-plugin-import` or `babel-plugin-transform-imports`. These configurations make sure only the files that you use from Material-UI are included in your builds.
2. Convert all you Material-UI `import` statements as such:

```js
-import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
-import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
+import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
```

Comment: I think you have it reversed. The docs suggest default imports instead of top level imports. I.e. `import X from "@material-ui/core/X"`;

Comment: The person answering is correct, if you scroll further down the docs it says that you can do it this way if you setup the babel config.